# How can I make sure this method closes the outputstream?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, io

How can I make sure that this method closes the OutputStream so a memory-leak won't happen?

```
public static void store(Properties properties, Class script) throws IOException {
    ScriptManifest scriptManifest = (ScriptManifest) script.getAnnotation(ScriptManifest.class);
    if (scriptManifest != null) {
        String name = scriptManifest.name();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Constants.SCRIPT_PROPERTIES_DIR + File.separator + name + ".properties");
        properties.store(outputStream, "");
        outputStream.close();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Script " + script.getName() + " does not have a ScriptManifest.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, I ment OutputStream.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Example:

```
public static void store(Properties properties, Class script) throws IOException {
    ScriptManifest scriptManifest = (ScriptManifest) script.getAnnotation(ScriptManifest.class);
    if (scriptManifest != null) {
        String name = scriptManifest.name();
        try ( FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Constants.SCRIPT_PROPERTIES_DIR + File.separator + name + ".properties") ) {
            properties.store(outputStream, "");
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Script " + script.getName() + " does not have a ScriptManifest.");
    }
}
```

or try with finally block like this:

```
public static void store(Properties properties, Class script) throws IOException {
    ScriptManifest scriptManifest = (ScriptManifest) script.getAnnotation(ScriptManifest.class);
    if (scriptManifest != null) {
        String name = scriptManifest.name();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Constants.SCRIPT_PROPERTIES_DIR + File.separator + name + ".properties");
            properties.store(outputStream, "");
        } finally {
            if ( outputStream != null ) outputStream.close();
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Script " + script.getName() + " does not have a ScriptManifest.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
  outputStream = new FileOutputStream(...)
  ...
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(...)
 }
 finally {
    // or use the Apache Commons IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    // and then only need the one line
    if (outputStream != null) {
      try {
         outputStream.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ignore) { }
    }
 }
```

In later versions of Java, you can use the try-with-resources

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("f:/tmp/stops.csv")) {
}
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without removing the throws ....?

Comment: @user2997204, in either approach, you can still throw a different exception (from IOException) if desired. I made an edit in the first example to illustrate.